# Сортировка строки в python

Tags: python

Пример случайных строк "ххллеебб" или "ва**бх**ыфав**е**ыываф**л**"

Как собрать слово "хлебхлеб","хлеб"?

не могу решить задачку (( на codeforces

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/393/A?locale=ru

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте условие задачи в сам вопрос. Вопрос должен быть максимально самодостаточен, ссылки могут приводиться для дополнительной информации - сейчас наоборот вся основная информация находится по ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово `хлеб` принципиально отличается от слова `nineteen` из задания тем, что не заканчивается на ту же букву с которой начинается.

Вам требуется посчитать буквы `n`, `i`, `e` и `t` в строке и выяснить, на сколько полных слов их хватит.

На каждое слово требуется две буквы `n`, одна `i`, три `e` и одна `t`, а также еще одна лишняя `n` на всех (`nineteenineteen` это два слова)